# Converting numeric variables to character in SAS

Tags: sas, character, numeric

I have two datasets, both with same variable names. In one of the datasets two variables have character format, however in the other dataset all variables are numeric. I use the following code to convert numeric variables to character, but the numbers are changing by 490.6 -> 491.
How can I do the conversion so that the numbers wouldn't change?

> ```
> data tst ;
> set data (rename=(Day14=Day14_Character Day2=Day2_Character)) ;
> Day14 = put(Day14_Character, 8.) ;
> Day2 = put(Day2_Character, 8.) ;
>  drop Day14_Character Day2_Character ;
>  run;
> ```

Comment: What is the length(s) of the character variable(s) you are trying to match?

Answer (score 2):

I always just use the `cats()` function to convert numeric to char.  The function concatenates and trims spaces from a list of character and/or numeric values and performs type conversion if necessary.

It's nice because I don't need to worry about whitespace, left/right-aligning, or formats when doing the conversion.

`Day14 = cats(Day14_Character);`

Answer (score 0):

Change the format to something like Best8.2:

```
 data tst ;
   set data (rename=(Day14=Day14_Character Day2=Day2_Character)) ;
   Day14 = put(Day14_Character, best8.2) ;
   Day2 = put(Day2_Character, best8.2) ;
   drop Day14_Character Day2_Character ;
 run;
```

Here is an example:

```
 data test;
   input r ;
   datalines;
   500.04
   490.6
   ;
 run;

 data test1;
   set test;
   num1 = put(r, 8.2);
 run;
```

If you do not want to specify the width and number of decimal points you can just use the `BEST.` informat and SAS will automatically assign the width and decimals based on the input data. However the length of the outcome variable may be large unless you specify it explicitly. This will still retain your numbers as in the original variable.

Comment: I think `8.2` is correct, not `best8.2`.  [`best`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/leforinforref/63324/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1fum54c93f8r0n1wrs5mrb05nzi.htm) shouldn't be used with a decimal, it only is `bestw.`.

Comment: @JohnDoe The point of the `bestw.` format (notice it does not have a `d`, which I think is what you're referring to) is that SAS will calculate the  best way to use the width (based on the individual values).  Hence it does not include a number after the decimal.  If you want to specify, you use `w.d` (`8.2` here).  If you want it to be more like a floating point where it can shift, you use `bestw.` instead.  But never `bestw.d`, as that doesn't exist.

Comment: You may be confusing it with the [`bestdw.p`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/leforinforref/63324/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0wi1eyjui7p3fn1g7912tl3lqyg.htm) format, which is different (note the d) and has a different overall effect. It's certainly overkill here.

Comment: @Joe, you&#39;re right,  thanks for pointing that out, although best8.2 did yield the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Your posted code is confused. Half of it looks like code to convert from character to numeric and half looks like it is for the other direction.

To convert to character use the `PUT()` function.  Normally you will want to left align the resulting string.  You can use the `-L` modifier on the end of the format specification to left align the value.

So to convert numeric variables DAY14 and DAY2 to character variables of length $8 you could use code like this:

```
data want ;
  set have (rename=(Day14=Day14_Numeric Day2=Day2_Numeric)) ;
  Day14 = put(Day14_Numeric, best8.-L) ;
  Day2  = put(Day2_Numeric, best8.-L) ;
  drop Day14_Numeric Day2_Numeric ;
run;
```

Remember you use `PUT` statement or `PUT()` function with **formats** to convert values to text. And you use the `INPUT` statement or `INPUT()` function with **informats** to convert text to values.

Comment: I would explain why you use `best` here, what it does as opposed to `8.`.